# Accuracy of GARCH& ARCH forecast

Tags: time-series, r, garch

I'm learing ARCH&GARCH model. I have four questions that I don't know the answers

1st: ARCH & GARCH are often used to evaluate equities. Does it mean that ARCH and GARCH are fitter for high volatility market?

2nd: Can I use these two models to estimate Interest Rate market?

3rd: If yes, the accuracy of forecasting depends on lag? In another word, the longer the lag, the better of forecasting?

Ex: if lag is 1 day, I can estimate tomorrow's price by today's price. If lag is 3 day, I can estimate price in 3 day from today's price.

4th: What's the right maximum likelihood function so that I can estimate all parameters in R language?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot predict prices with ARCH/GARCH. They are models for volatility...

Comment: I agree, but in these models rt is the log daily return. I can predit price by rt=ln(P(t+1)/P(t)),right?

Comment: No, you start with fitting for example some ARMA model and then try to look for ARCH-effects of the residuals. I would recommend starting by looking into the basics first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few comments on your questions:

1) Yes, Arch and Garch are suitable for equities volatility, please see:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.800/pdf

2) No. These are models of volatility. To model interest rates use CIR, Vasicek or similar.

3) and 4) Check paper above.